# Is it possible to make a group a site collection owner in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, site-collection, groups, site

I have a SharePoint Online site collection and I have a SharePoint group on the main site in that site collection that I would like to make a site collection owner. Is this possible, maybe through PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think so.
Site collection admin should be Azure AD identity (group or user). It exists at tenant level.
SharePoint group exists within SharePoint site.

Instead you should be able to create an AAD Security Group (login to https://portal.azure.com/, then Azure Active Directory, Groups, + New Group), wait ~10 minute, then you can

- manage group membership
- use this group in your site

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for Sharepoint groups no, and this has been a long standing caveat with Site Collection Administrators - they can only be defined users.

You can use Azure AD / Office 365 Security Groups though.

[This link to previous question explains this well this very well.](https://kirkbarrett.wordpress.com/2016/04/04/adding-an-o365-security-group-to-the-site-collection-administrators-group/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make a SharePoint Group as site collection administrator. As a workaround, you could make an offcie 365 group as site collection administrator.

Create a Office 365 group and add users to it. Then go to SharePoint admini center, choose the site and click permissions. Add the Office group as admin.
[image]